# Adding additional rows in report's Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on *JR* reports and using *iReport* to generate them.

I'm looking for solution for this task: the *Detail* band must have six records. For example, the query fetch 3 records from database then the detail band will have 3 rows, but I want to print 3 remaining rows as blank rows.

How can I do it with *iReport*?

Answer (score 2):

The best way i can think to do this is to make your query return 6 rows (or your set # of rows) then there is no need for jasper to do anything out of the ordinary.

Here is an example of how you might do that with oracle 10 or greater -- I am sure there are better way to do this.

`with gen_6

     -- creates a table of 6 rows (generate series)

     as (SELECT     LEVEL as row_num

         FROM       dual

         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6),

     

     Your_Query as`

```
 -- your query here <BR>
    (select SYSDATE, ROWNUM as row_num from dual where rownum <=6)<BR>
```

select   *
from     gen_6 left join your_query using (row_num)
order by row_num

FYI

You do not even need to add the "field" row_num to your report for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way**: you just need to include N Textfields on detail band to duplicate the number of records from the data source or hardcode the number needed.

Example:

```
Detail Band
----------------
| FIELD_X
| FIELD_X
----------------
```

In this case you will receive 3 records from DB and will print 6 values.

**Another option**: Create two subreports with the rules that you need and include it on the details page, one then other in onother line.

Example:

```
Detail Band
----------------
| SUBREPORT_1
| SUBREPORT_2
----------------
```

In this case you will receive 3 records from DB and will print 3 values in each subreport, so in the second subreport you can leave the rows in blank or any other rule.

**Business Example:** 
This approach can be used for financial interfaces where different accounts need to be assigned for a particular credit or debit.

Comment: `you just need to include N Textfields on detail band to duplicate the number of records from the data source or hardcode the number needed.` - the number of rows that returned with query is variable, I believe. This solution is not working

Comment: @AlexK please provide a better description of what is your scenario of configuration then maybe I can help you, the scenario that you included originally can be solved with this solution stated, but if you are thinking in a different context please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Limit your query's result to 6, then do the usual, put the fields in the detail band

Then, in the summary, create three lines of fields.

```
   1 |    ||    ||    ||    |
   2 |    ||    ||    ||    |
   3 |    ||    ||    ||    |
```

**In the `Print When Expression` of the all the fields in the first line**

`new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == 3 || $V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == 4 || $V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == 5)`

**In the `Print When Expression` of the all the fields in the second line**

`new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == 3 || $V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == 4)`

**In the `Print When Expression` of the all the fields in the third line**

`new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == 3)`

The position of the first line of fields should be at the top most of the summary band so that the fields will look like as if they are part of the details section.